# "The requested URL was not found on this server" after TYPO3 installation

Tags: php, apache, typo3, typo3-11.x

After I have installed TYPO3 on my local host this error occurs

> The requested URL was not found on this server

I can show the login page of admin. After entering the credentials then occurs this error.

Comment: Please check, if your `.htaccess` files are correct and the correct ones for your current TYPO3 version.

Comment: i did n't do anything on .htaccess file. just installed. my php version is 7.4 and typo3 version is 11

Comment: Does your environment allow the use of `.htaccess`-files? And are the required apache-modules installed?

Answer (score 1):

As written by Julian you need to make sure that there is the correct `.htaccess` file in your document root directory.

If the file is missing, you can find a sample file here:
`/typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess`

Answer (score 1):

sometimes deleting .htaccess was the solution.  (typo3 Install-Tool Environment offers to try repairing it. )
Rename your .htaccess, so you are able to compare differences later

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This happens when upgrading from typo3 v10 to v11. The typo3v10 .htaccess is still used, and it does not have rewrites for `/typo3/`.

Remove the `public/.htaccess` file and run the install tool in `/typo3/install.php` and let the "Directory status" tool re-create it.